# How to add 0 to the beginning of a value in Excel if the value is a certain length

Tags: excel

I don't really have good knowledge of excel function, but I am hoping this is something i can do in an excel spreadsheet instead of writing a text parser to do this and have to put the data back in.

I basically want to do this in excel:

`IF cellValueLength = 4 characters OR cellValueLength = 9 characters THEN cellValue = "0" + cellValue`

Sorry for the weird pseudo code, but I'm not sure how else to clearly communicate what I am trying to accomplish.

Also the cell values can be strings. In fact I'd prefer if they were all strings since Excel automatically converting them to numbers is what messed this up in the first place.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: say in B1: `=IF(OR(LEN(A1)=4,LEN(A1)=9),"0","") & A1`?

Comment: How did you get the file into excel? If you still have the original file, you could try re-importing it. The Data Import Wizard can format the data as text for plain text and csv files, so that you won't lose leading zeroes.

Comment: @Simoco, thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. You should post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Jerry I got it using SQL, but I know a lot of the time when it comes to data, string parsing, and other simple stuff what is 10 lines in SQL or 50 lines using a programming language is one simple line in Excel

Comment: @Adam You mean that the data was already that way in SQL? Because if you import it from the Data > Get Data From External Sources > From SQL Server, you shouldn't get that problem. Also, if it's possible to fix it in SQL itself, I believe it's better, because excel has limitations that SQL doesn't, like the number of records.

Comment: @Simoco In the SQL table, the field was an NVARCHAR, I wrote a query to retrieve it using server management studio as it was coming from multiple tables and needed some filtering. I copied the results into Excel. I forgot that Excel tries to automatically format anything that looks like a number as a number, but I had already edited much of the spreadsheet before I noticed. Thank you for that suggestion though, I didn't know you could import data from a SQL table to Excel.

Comment: @Adam There's your culprit. Copy/Pasting does that to your data, unless you click on the little [Paste Icon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gwzVX.jpg) that appears and using the Text Import Wizard and opting to import with format Text avoids this, or alternatively import directly from the SQL table through the method I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works:

```
=IF(OR(LEN(A1)=4,LEN(A1)=9),"0","") & A1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this done "in place", then select the cells and run this macro:

```
Sub PreZero()
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        If Len(v) = 4 Then
            r.NumberFormat = "00000"
        End If
        If Len(v) = 9 Then
            r.NumberFormat = "0000000000"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In the format menu you should be able to format the cells as numbers and make it the way you described.

I hope this helped you!